# How do I write subscripts in the middle of a string?

Tags: subscript

As stated in the tile, I want to have a subscript in the middle of a sting, but `StringJoin` does not allow `"Test"<>Subscript["test", "test"]<>"test"`.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11):

When you convert the subscripts to strings be sure to choose `StandardForm`:

```
"Test  " <> ToString[Subscript["x", "21"], StandardForm] <> "  test"
```

[image]

Here is it again saved as a PDF:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
StringInsert["David", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(a\), \(b\)]\)", 3]
```

(*
$\text{Da}a_b\text{vid}$
*)

or

```
"David" <> "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(c\), \(d\)]\)" <> "cat"
```

(* 
$\text{David}c_d\text{cat}$
*)

Comment: This doesn't produce a string containing subscript glyphs. It won't look like subscripted text anywhere outside of *Mathematica*

Answer (score 2):

Subscripting is a formatting operation for displayed output only. You can't put *Mathematica* subscripting into a string object which can only contain unicode characters. You *can* put unicode subscript characters into string.

[image]

> ```
> "test\:2084\:2082"
> ```

Answer (score 1):

building on David's answer, supposing we have a `Subscript` object:

```
  s = Subscript[a, b];
```

you can roll that into a string like this:

```
 sout = "the subscript form of a is: " <> "\!\(" <> 
        ToString[ToBoxes[s], InputForm] <> "\)"
```

[image]

note the string actually contains all that escape code:

```
 sout // FullForm
```

> "the subscript form of a is: !(\(a\_b\))"

hence the result is only useful for display within mathematica.

the docs on this were a little hard to find: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/StringRepresentationOfBoxes.html